# Magento rwd Theme Level 2 Category Menu

Tags: magento-1.9, category, rwd, rwd-theme

i have a Menu of 2 Levels. On the last level i want to show the categorys on the left sidebar.

Look here:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s312/sh/2f446214-27b3-4ded-90cc-c3227f104f6f/7153126e64017fe82181fbe8b8e0f233/deep/0/Sportbike-Masters-Lauf-9+10.png

How can i do this?

Comment: make sure your caterogies have "Is Anchor" set to "Yes"

Answer (score 1):

Just set 'Is Anchor' to yes on all the categories that you want to display layered navigation in the sidebar for.